# Why do college basketball teams often take a timeout just before half time?

Tags: basketball, collegiate

Something I can’t grasp my mind around is why college basketball coaches spend a timeout right before the end of the first half. It just doesn’t make sense to me. There are a finite numbers of timeouts and you spend one with 40 seconds before hitting the locker rooms?

Answer (score 3):

How many timeouts does the team have left?

NCAA timeout rules are a bit complex due to dependency on TV broadcast rules.  But if you're watching on national TV, they're probably playing under the "at least 3 media timeouts per half" rules.

Under these rules, if the team has not yet used any timeouts then one will be lost at the half (only two 30-second timeouts can carry over to the second half).

Since it would be lost anyway, a team with three remaining would not need much of an excuse to use one.

From the [NCAA Men's Basketball Rules](https://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/BK24-20231127.pdf)
Rule 5, Section 13, Article 10

> Art. 10. When the electronic-media agreement calls for AT LEAST THREE
> electronic-media timeouts in either half, the format shall be as
> follows:
>
> a. Three 30-second timeouts for each team per regulation
> game.
>
> 1. Each team may carry up to two 30-second timeouts into the second half.